# UR anomaly in parameter usage

Tags: java, sonarqube, lint, dataflow

The following piece of code is being flagged by SonarQube as having a UR anomaly when running [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3.0/rules/controversial.html) rules, which is baffling to me:

```
public void doSomething(String filename) {
    final Resource resource = new ClassPathResource(filename);
    //do something with the resource ...
}
```

I can understand a DU (because the variable is short lived) but why a UR?

According to data flow analysis papers UR stands for "Undefined-Referenced" and DU stands for "Defined-Undefined".

The first one refers to when you are referencing an undefined variable (a possible bug) and he second one refers to when a recently defined variable is undefined (such as when you go out of scope and that variable is de-referenced).

Comment: Uhm... could you spell out UR and DU?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592497/java-for-each-loop-being-flagged-as-ur-anomaly-by-pmd.

Comment: That would be really helpful to precise which rule is flagging an issue. I suspect that this is a PMD rule here given the link raised by @Jire ?

Comment: Indeed : http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3.0/rules/controversial.html see DataflowAnomalyAnalysis

Comment: It is a PMD rule. I just can't seem to understand why it is being flagged. I will update the question as well.