# Found 'UR'-anomaly for variable

Tags: sonarqube5.1

I have this sonar error Major:

> Found 'UR'-anomaly for variable 'language' (lines '83'-'85')

in this function:

```
public void saveAll(List<Language> languages){
   //Found 'UR'-anomaly for variable 'country' (lines '83'-'85').       
   //Code Smell   Major    Open    Not assigned   20min effort   Comment
   for (Language language: languages) {
        save(language);
   }
}
```

how to fix this major error please, thanks for advance

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**:
Found even more information it this other SO post. While that is more PMD centric, the background information can be of interest to you.
[Java for each loop being flagged as UR anomaly by PMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592497/java-for-each-loop-being-flagged-as-ur-anomaly-by-pmd).

---

This is a rule from PMD it seems. Definition:

> The dataflow analysis tracks local definitions, undefinitions and
>   references to variables on different paths on the data flow. From
>   those informations there can be found various problems. 1. UR -
>   Anomaly: There is a reference to a variable that was not defined
>   before. This is a bug and leads to an error. 2. DU - Anomaly: A
>   recently defined variable is undefined. These anomalies may appear in
>   normal source text. 3. DD - Anomaly: A recently defined variable is
>   redefined. This is ominous but don't have to be a bug.

There is an open bug report for this:
https://sourceforge.net/p/pmd/bugs/1190/

In the example they report it for Arrays, but somebody commented that it happens for them also for collections.

Example:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    for (final String string : args) {
        string.getBytes(); //UR Anomaly
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        args[i].getBytes();
    }
}
```

In our sonar setup we don't use this rule. Based on the available information you may wish not to use it in yours.